# No suitable driver found for jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050

Tags: jdbc, firebird, jaybird

I build a javafx maven app , using jaybird dependency . Every thing work fine from intelliJ.
when i export the jar file ,I receive this message :

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050...

[image]
[image: project structure]

this is dependencies part of pom.xml:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaybird-jdk16</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using to connect and your classpath. Most likely you don't have Jaybird on the class path at runtime (or if you created a fat-jar, you might have not properly merged or imported all resources Jaybird requires to load properly). Check your logs for exceptions, or try to explicitly load the driver with `Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver")` before trying to connect, and add the resulting exception to your question. As an aside, why are you using such an old version of Jaybird? Upgrade to Jaybird 4.0.3 (e.g. `org.firebirdsql.jdbc:jaybird:4.0.3.java8`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is :
right click on jaybird dependency(follow the image), then click **Extract into output root** then rebuild the artifact jar.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Mark Rotteveel ,you have inspired me something.

Answer (score 0):

The normal cause of this error occurring is that either you don't have Jaybird (Firebird JDBC driver) - or one of its required dependencies - on your classpath, or the driver was not registered. Driver registration normally happens automatically, but you can always try to do it explicitly using `Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver")`. If this fails, you get a stacktrace that provides further information.

Given you show a Maven pom.xml that includes Jaybird (albeit an older version), the driver is present at compile time. However, depending on how you launch your application, it may not be present on the runtime classpath.

There are several options:

1. Explicitly specify the driver when loading Java:

   ```
   java -cp yourapp.jar;jaybird-4.0.3.java8.jar;connector-api-1.5.jar your.class.Name
   ```

   Here, both `jaybird-4.0.3.java8.jar` and `connector-api-1.5.jar` are required for Jaybird to work.
2. List the required JARs (`jaybird-4.0.3.java8.jar` and `connector-api-1.5.jar`) in the `Class-Path` entry of the [manifest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) of your JAR:

   ```
   Class-Path: jaybird-4.0.3.java8.jar connector-api-1.5.jar
   ```

   Both jar files need to be in the same directory as your JAR. You can then launch your application as (assuming the `Main-Class` attribute is also specified):

   ```
   java -jar yourapp.jar
   ```
3. Create a fat (or uber) JAR, and make sure all of Jaybird's classes and resources - and those of its required dependencies - are included in your JAR.
4. (web applications) Include the driver (and dependencies) in the libraries/modules of your application server (e.g. the Tomcat `lib` folder), or make sure the driver is included in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your WAR (the Maven WAR plugin takes care of this). In this last case (driver in `WEB-INF/lib`), it is necessary to explicitly load the driver using `Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver")` to ensure the driver is registered.